# Having difficulty iterating through an Object of Arrays and generating dynamic React elements in JSX from within the Redux Store

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I am fetching some data from an API and organizing it into an `Object` of `Arrays` - Each `Array` is an `Array` of `Objects` itself

```
const menuItems = { 
    Dinner: [{_id: "2af4", itemName: "Filtet Mignon"}],
    Fruit: [{_id: "41gg", itemName: "Strawberries"}, {_id: "2fas", itemName: "Apple"}, {_id: "gkkm", itemName: "Pear"}],
    Lunch: [{_id: "fmuu" itemName:"Artichoke Pizza"}]

}
```

These items are fetched from the API and stored in the Redux Store.

I am successfully using `connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)` to bring these items within the scope of my Component's bound functions.

I would like to create a `<div>` or `<button>` element for each item, but my methods do not seem to be working. This is what I have tried:

```
iterateThruObject() {
    const { menuItems } = this.props

    return Object.keys(menuItems).forEach((k) => { 
        return menuItems[k].map(item => <div key={item._id}>{item.itemName}</div>)
    })
}

render() {
 const { menuItems } = this.props
  return(
     {menuItems && this.iterateThruObject()}
  )}
```

As far as I can see - this should be working. The `iterateThruObject()` is being properly triggered, and if I put `console.log()` inside, I can see all of the different properties being cycled through. So I confused why the `<div>` elements are not being created.

I have tried to use a `for...in` loop to iterate through the Object, but the loop terminates early at the first `return`

If anyone can help me with this, point me to my mistake, I would really appreciate it.

Here are the `console.log` entries so the data structure is easier to visualize:

```
console.log(Object.keys(menuItems))
// ["Dinner", "Fruit", "Lunch"]

 console.log(menuItems[k]) // 3 Invocations within .forEach()
// Array [{_id: "2af4", itemName: "Filtet Mignon"}]
// Array [{_id: "41gg", itemName: "Strawberries"}, {_id: "2fas", itemName: "Apple"}, {_id: "gkkm", itemName: "Pear"}]
// Array [{_id: "fmuu" itemName:"Artichoke Pizza"}]

menuItems[k].map(item => console.log(item.itemName)) // 3 .map() Invocations
// Filet Mignon - Iteration 1
// Strawberries - Iteration 2
// Apple - Iteration 2
// Pear - Iteration 2
// Artichoke Pizza - Iteration 3
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in iterateThruObject. (You're only returning the value of each forEach iteration.
So `return Object.keys......` should help

Comment: I have edited my code with this solution and there are still no div being generated, strangely enough

Comment: Oh right, a forEach doesn't actually return anything, replacing it with a .map should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.map` instead of `forEach` so an object will get returned:

```
return Object.keys(menuItems).map((k) => {
  return menuItems[k].map(item => <div key={item._id}>{item.itemName}</div>)
})
```

Note that `forEach` [will always return `undefined`, unlike `map` or reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description):

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
>   not chainable.

Running example:

```js
const data = {
  Dinner: [{ _id: "2af4", itemName: "Filtet Mignon" }],
  Fruit: [{ _id: "41gg", itemName: "Strawberries" }, { _id: "2fas", itemName: "Apple" }, { _id: "gkkm", itemName: "Pear" }],
  Lunch: [{ _id: "fmuu", itemName: "Artichoke Pizza" }]

}

class App extends React.Component {
  iterateThruObject = () => {
    const { menuItems } = this.props

    return Object.keys(menuItems).map((k) => {
      return menuItems[k].map(item => <div key={item._id}>{item.itemName}</div>)
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { menuItems } = this.props;
    return (
      <div >
        {menuItems && this.iterateThruObject()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App menuItems={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```